# script error: end of line, etc. expected (s) but class name found. launch Xcode projet (run)

Tags: xcode, applescript

```
tell application "Xcode"    
  activate
  set targetProject to project of active project document
  if (build targetProject) is equal to "Build succeeded" then
      launch targetProject
  end if
end tell
```

> example.scpt: 81: 88: script error: end of line, etc. expected (s) but class name found. (-2741)

Comment: I formatted your code using the code format tool, and formatted your error as a quote, but the question is still missing your question. Please edit the question and add words telling us what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode (9) does not have a `active project document` property.

You probably mean

```
set targetProject to project of active workspace document
```